# How to indent bullet ppt vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint, indentation, bulletedlist

I'm having an issue with bullets in VBA on a text box in a PPT file.

I use the following code to modify existing text in bullets :

> ```
> PptDoc.Slides(3).Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "1" & Chr(13) & "2" & Chr(13) & "3"
> ```

It gives me :

- 1
- 2
- 3

I would like to make a sub bullet with "4" under the "3".
I tried this :

> ```
> .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "1" & Chr(13) & "2" & Chr(13) & "3" & chr(13) & chr(9)& "4"
> ```

It only gives me :

- 1
- 2
- 3
- {Some Space}4

But id does not what I want. I tried with .IndentLevel, but never success.

Where am I wrong ?

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT : I have tried some propositions, but it never works on my presentation here is what I tried :

```
> .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(4).IndentLevel = 2
> 
> .TextFrame.TextRange.Lines(4).IndentLevel = 2
```

Each time, it does absolutely nothing, I can see IndentLevel growing, but my bullet do not indent.

Comment: Try `PptDoc.Slides(3).Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(4).IndentLevel = 2` after you enter the text

Comment: This is not working here :(

Comment: May I see your powerpoint file? If yes, please upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here. Also please confirm the MS Office Version.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that extra space because you have `chr(9)` in your original code and that is a **Tab** character. So try `vbCrLf` (which is carriage return followed by line feed) instead of the `chr(13) & chr(9)`.

```
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "1" & vbCrLf & "2" & vbCrLf & "3" & vbCrLf & "4"
```

Comment: This does not indent the fourth line for me

Comment: I think it may depend on the style definitions of the Presentation

Comment: Ahh - I think you may have misread the questions. The issue isn't getting bullets to appear - it is _further_ indenting_ additional bullets. Both the `Chr(9)` and `vbCrLf` methods generate simple bulleted list but they do not indent the fourth bullet as the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a basic slide with a standard text box as the second 'Shape'. The following code indents the fourth line to the second bullet level (`IndentLevel = 4`). Your IndentLevels may be specified differently but this should provide a generic framework from which a solution can be crafted.

This works for me:

```
Sub pleaseIndentBullets()

    Dim pres As Presentation
    Dim sd As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim tr As TextRange

    Dim s As String

    s = "1" & Chr(13) & "2" & Chr(13) & "3" & Chr(13) & "4" ' Chr(9) is tab but this doesn't work
    Set pres = ActiveWindow.Presentation
    Set sd = pres.Slides(pres.Slides.Count)
    Set shp = sd.Shapes(2)
    Set tr = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
    tr.Text = s
    tr.Lines(4).IndentLevel = 4

End Sub
```

Comment: As Sid commented above, you could use `Paragraphs` just as well as `Lines`. It's probably more robust to use `Paragraphs`

Comment: I might have a real issue somewhere, none of these are working :( 
In my slide, if I juste type tab on the last line, it indent, I can't believe, this is killing me

Comment: Try this on a new, blank presentation. Create a basic title + content slide. See if it works - play with the IndentLevel (set it to 1, 2, 3, 4) and see if it makes a difference. Report back

Comment: On a new blank presentation it correctly works. I'm not understanding why not in mine.

Comment: You may have defined your inbuilt styles to not indent _any_ level of bulletting. You can change this [here for 2003] (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint-help/change-the-default-bullet-or-numbering-style-HP003076004.aspx) or [here for later versions] (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint-help/change-the-color-and-style-of-a-bulleted-or-numbered-list-HA102850242.aspx?CTT=1)